# Collect map from other map by stream

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have such code:

```
Map<Integer, Settings> operatorsSettings = new HashMap<>();
operators.forEach((operator, codeTypes) -> operatorsSettings.put(operator, mapper.convertValue(codeTypes.get(SETTINGS), Settings.class)));
return operatorsSettings;
```

I wrote it but i wonder. Is it possible to write it without creating a new map. Something like this (**not correct code**):

```
return operators.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(entry -> Collectors.toMap(entry.getKey() , mapper.convertValue(entry.getValue().get(SETTINGS), Settings.class)));
```

Comment: Have you tried using [Map.merge](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2019/03/mapmerge-one-method-to-rule-them-all.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, you just made a small syntax mistake...

```
return operators.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey() , mapper.convertValue(entry.getValue().get(SETTINGS), Settings.class)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in plain java:

```
return operators.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey() , entry -> mapper.convertValue(entry.getValue().get(SETTINGS), Settings.class)));
```

or you can use streamex library and write it like this:

```
EntryStream.of(operatorsSettings).mapValues(codeTypes -> mapper.convertValue(codeTypes.get(SETTINGS), Settings.class))...
```